# Right align syntax doesnt show up in the output

Tags: math-mode, align

[image]I dont know why, but my align syntax doesnt show up in the output. My boyfriend tested this syntax on his sharelatex.com account and it works there. I tried to sign up again but it doesnt change anything. This is my syntax:

```
\begin{align*}
    \Vec{r}(Q) &= \frac{1}{2} (\Vec{r}(P_1)+\Vec{r}(P_2))=\\
    &= \frac{1}{2}(\left(\begin{array}{c}
         1\\
         2\\ 
    \end{array}\right) + \left(\begin{array}{c}
         -2\\
         3\\ 
    \end{array}\right) )=\\
     &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{c}
         -1\\
         5\\
    \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}
         -0,5\\
         2,5\\ 
    \end{array}\right)\\

    Q=(-0,5;2,5)\\
\end{align*}
```

I need the help immediately.have a lot math-stuff to write in latex.

Comment: Please add a MWE (minimal working example) and not just a code snippet,

Comment: first of all, don't leave blank lines in any math environment.  not allowed -- will always fail.  add `&` before the `=` after "Q" in last line.  and look at the `pmatrix` environment from `amsmath`.

Comment: Is `Q&=(-0,5;2,5)` what you are seeking? (`&` added)

Comment: I can reproduce the issue. Just remove the blank line before ``Q=(-0,5;2,5)\\`` (which should probably be `Q&=(-0,5;2,5)`; the ``\\`` should be removed, the `&` depends on the alignment you wish to get).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to eliminating the blank line in your input, you may want to consider using a `pmatrix*` environment instead of the generic (and much more loosely spaced!) `array` environment for the four 2x1 column vectors. Furthermore, I recommend encasing the decimal commas in curly braces, in order to keep TeX from interpreting the commas as punctuation characters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'pmatrix*' env.
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\Vec{r}(Q) &= \tfrac{1}{2} \bigl(\Vec{r}(P_1)+\Vec{r}(P_2) \bigr) \\
           &= \frac{1}{2} \left[
              \begin{pmatrix*}[r] 1\\2 \end{pmatrix*} +
              \begin{pmatrix*}[r] -2\\3\end{pmatrix*} 
              \right] \\
           &= \frac{1}{2}
              \begin{pmatrix*}[r] -1\\5\end{pmatrix*} =
              \begin{pmatrix*}[r]-0{,}5\\ 2{,}5 \end{pmatrix*}\\
Q &= (-0{,}5;2{,}5)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Just for the sake of comparison, here's a screenshot produced by your original code (after the spurious blank line is removed and an `&` alignment character is inserted in the final row):

[image]